# Is this acceptable use of location authorization callback?

Tags: ios, swift, core-location

I have implemented a location authorization callback function and it works, but looking over the code I seem to have got the function to trigger but never actually use the function as intended. Please can you comment on how bad I am being and if it is acceptable to do what I have done.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation


class ViewController___Main_menu: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    let locationManager = CLLocationManager()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            print("services are enabled")
            switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
            case .notDetermined:
                print("Not determined")
            case .restricted:
                print("Resticted")
            case .denied:
                print("Denied")
            case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
                print("Access")
            @unknown default:
                print("unknown error")
            }
        } else {
        print("not enabled")
        }

    }


    public func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus){
        print("Status: \(status)")
        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {
        case .notDetermined:
            print("Not determined")
        case .restricted:
            print("Resticted")
        case .denied:
            print("Denied")
        case .authorizedAlways, .authorizedWhenInUse:
            print("Access")
        @unknown default:
            print("unknown error")
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: If your goal is to print the location services status then your code is ok. But that `if` statement is not a "callback". If you implemented location manager delegate methods those would be your callbacks. It is rather unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Yes thank you, the intention was to make sure the authorization pop-up occurs whilst also using the if statement to determine what I should display and print. I'm going to re-jig it so it incorporates Nevan post as well. Thank you for your post

Answer (score 0):

It's looks like you're requesting access to location services and straight after that checking what the authorization status is, expecting it to be available immediately. This isn't the way it works. When you request location with `locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization` the request happens asynchronously.

When the location status changes then it will call to the function you're included `locationManager(_:didChangeAuthorization)` with the new status. This will happen when the user taps "Allow" or "Deny" on the prompt that appears. It can also happen when they go into the settings and change the permissions there

So to make it more clear, check and log the authorization status before requesting location. Use the following methods to know if the location request succeeded or failed:

`func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations: [CLLocation])`
`func locationManager(CLLocationManager, didFailWithError: Error)`

You would use the `CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled()` check to wrap the request for location services. If location is turned off for the device then requesting location will just cause an error.

Comment: Thank you, you've made me realise the order I should do things and will update my code accordingly, Thanks !